# Is there a good way to handle element as single vs array in?

Tags: javascript, json

We don't want to go through the pain of putting square brackets even if single element on server side, since that will put extra overhead.

At the same time want to make sure on JavaScript side its not going to add extra work to handle it not knowing that users or joined objects can be an array or just a single object.
What will be the best way to handle it in JavaScript (if any) or we should plan to do that on server side -

```
{"users":[
        {
            "firstName":"Ray",
             "joined": {
                "month":"January",
            }
        },
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "joined": {
                "month":"April",
            }
        }
]}
```

VS.

```
{"users":
        {
            "firstName":"Ray",
             "joined": [
                {
                "month":"January",
                },
                {
                "month":"Feruary",
                },
            ]
        }
}
```

I am converting xml to json using an XSLT. Since the conversion is generic and unaware of XML Schema, It is going to generate square brackets or not depending upon the XML data.

I am not an expert on javascript so wanted to check on this before customizing response on server side.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what overhead are you worried about? In most languages arrays are usually about as efficient a collection as you can get... I'd suspect that adding an extra flag and a check to determine the format of the JSON is worse (in resources, time and bug risk) than just having an array with a single element!

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: So you don't want to deal with the "pain" of returning an array containing a single element, but you're more than happy to write code that deals with different data types for a property in JavaScript...? Even though, based on asking this question, you don't actually know how to do that.

Comment: I agree with everyone else, you are looking for a solution to the wrong problem. You need to standardize your json output, not customize your javascript to handle all potential results.  Most server side languages allow you to serialize objects into JSON.  It sounds like you're building your JSON manually, which you shouldn't.

Comment: i am using an integration tool on server side. making xml to json conversion on server side schema aware is certainly an option if this is overhead on javascript side. Wanted to check since doing that on server side is moving from generic conversion to customized for each XML.

Answer (score 0):

Users should always be a collection as it is plural, even if there is just one.

I would use json.net for this i.e.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
```

Comment: This is assuming he's using c# and has json.net installed.